# What is the standard exception to throw in Java for not supported/implemented operations?

Tags: java

In particular, is there a standard `Exception` subclass used in these circumstances?

Comment: Is it appropriate to use when a class does not implement a method, but child classes may do so? In other words, to have an abstract method in a non-abstract class.

Comment: @SergeyOrshanskiy It's useful for when, depending on how you construct an object, you need to create an anonymous class that implements an interface in order to instantiate a member variable, but you don't want it to be used. If you set it to `null` and you accidentally used it (or someone else did) you would get `NullPointerExceptions` which are less obvious than `UnsupportedOperationExceptions` in this case. Just an example.

Answer (score 576, accepted):

From the Java documentation:

> Thrown to indicate that the requested operation is not supported.
>
> ― [java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html)

Example usage:

```java
throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Feature incomplete. Contact assistance.");
```

Comment: @JarrodRoberson OK, that statement should really be removed from the class documentation in that case. The exception does seem to be used by other packages. I guess if Oracle does so, then so should we. I'll file a bug report.

Comment: Be aware this is an _unchecked_ `RuntimeException`.  You will get no feedback or assistance in handling these exceptions during compile time.  If this is used for a stubbed method or a work-in-progress you should use some kind of _checked_ exception.

Comment: You might wanna do it like this to indicate, that the implementation is yet to come:

    throw new java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented yet."); //todo implement

Comment: It can be puzzling to find public API methods that don't implement logic yet and return `null` value. I prefer having a method returning `UnsupportedOperationException`. I use this myself and rewrite any existing code with this exception, when obviously no logic was implemented.

Answer (score 259):

Differentiate between the two cases you named:

- To indicate that the requested operation is not supported and most likely never will, throw an [`UnsupportedOperationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html).
- To indicate the requested operation has not been implemented yet, choose between this:

  1. Use the [`NotImplementedException`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/NotImplementedException.html) from [apache commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) which was available in commons-lang2 and has been re-added to commons-lang3 in version 3.2.
  2. Implement your own `NotImplementedException`.
  3. Throw an [`UnsupportedOperationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html) with a message like "Not implemented, yet".

Comment: I am going with this, because it seems reasonable to me. "Yet" or "never" indicated by the Exception gives an idea on how to react on this.

Comment: #s 1 or 2 are greatly preferable in practice. #3 does capture the semantic distinction between "not supported" and "not implemented", but having a separate class makes it easier to do a quick search to verify that you haven't forgotten to implement anything you should before committing.

Comment: #3 is best for not implemented methods as it doesn't require a third party library or additional work, even if it is commons-lang.

Answer (score 43):

If you create a new (not yet implemented) function in [**NetBeans**](https://netbeans.org/), then it generates a method body with the following statement:

```
throw new java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
```

Therefore, I recommend to use the [UnsupportedOperationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html).

Answer (score 16):

If you want more granularity and better description, you could use `NotImplementedException` from [`commons-lang`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/NotImplementedException.html)

Warning: Available before versions 2.6 and after versions 3.2 only.

Answer (score 8):

The below `Calculator` sample class shows the difference

```
public class Calculator() {

 int add(int a , int b){
    return a+b;
  }

  int dived(int a , int b){
        if ( b == 0 ) {
           throw new UnsupportedOperationException("I can not dived by zero, 
                         not now not for the rest of my life!")
        }else{
          return a/b;
       }
   }

   int multiple(int a , int b){
      //NotImplementedException from apache or some custom excpetion
      throw new NotImplementedException("Will be implement in release 3.5");
   } 
}
```